# Why am I getting an error in my .js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, axios

Why am I getting that `error` below in the browser?  I just want to display the `Flights` component in `App` but I get that `error`.

Why am I getting that error and how can I fix it?

Here's `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Title from './components/Title/Title';
import Aux from './hoc/Aux';
import Flights from './components/Flights/Flights';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Aux>
          <Title/>
          <Flights/>
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here's `Flights.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Flights extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums')
            .then(response => {
                console.log("API Call ====> " + response);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>Here are the songs:</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Flights;
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
./src/components/Flights/Flights.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 
'/Users/name/WebstormProjects/flights/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js' in 
'/Users/name/WebstormProjects/flights'
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you didn't install the `babel-loader` into your project.

You have to install babel-loader into your devDependencies:

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-loader
```

In case you're using Yarn

```
$ yarn add babel-loader
```

Or just run `npm install` or `yarn install` to install/update all packages you added to you package.json.

Comment: hmm, I used `create-react-app` to start my project, I never had to do this before when I started new projects.

Comment: im using npm, npm install didn't work.  I already had node_modules folder upon creating my project

Comment: Try to remove your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again.